# jpa inbound-channel-adapter doesn't support parameter source

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to use the parameter-source to provide a parameter to my query in the inbound-channel-adapter but it doesn't seem to work.  I have looked through the Parser code and I don't think it is processing the parameter-source.

```
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter delete-after-poll="true"
    delete-in-batch="true" auto-startup="true" flush-after-delete="true"
    max-results="2000"
    entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"
    entity-class="AuditMessage"
    channel="processMessage"
    jpa-query="select a from AuditMessage a where a.updateTs &lt; :purgeDate"
    parameter-source="parameterSource">
    <int:poller cron="*/5 * * * * *" >
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="parameterSource" factory-bean="spelSource"
            factory-method="createParameterSourceNoCache">
    <constructor-arg value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="spelSource"
    class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
    <property name="parameterExpressions">
        <map>
            <entry key="purgeDate"
                value="new java.sql.Timestamp(T(System).currentTimeMillis()-(T(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit).MILLISECONDS.convert(${eam.integration.arcgis.purge.daysToKeep}, T(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit).DAYS)))" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I get the following exception:

```
ERROR [task-scheduler-9] [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Query has parameters but no parameter source provided
at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.DefaultJpaOperations.setParametersIfRequired(DefaultJpaOperations.java:330)
at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.DefaultJpaOperations.getQuery(DefaultJpaOperations.java:114)
at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.DefaultJpaOperations.getResultListForQuery(DefaultJpaOperations.java:186)
at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.JpaExecutor.doPoll(JpaExecutor.java:396)...
```

I am on spring version 4.0.3. Am I doing something wrong?  Or is there another way to provide query parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've just found a bug!

The `JpaInboundChannelAdapterParser` just doesn't parse the `parameter-source` attrbiute. Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) bug.

As a workaround you must configure `JpaPollingChannelAdapter` as a raw `<bean>` with injection of `JpaExecutor` and use it as a `ref` from generic `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

The JIRA [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3767) for those who would like to track.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and thanks for adding the JIRA ticket.